# How to track finger movement using touch events

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to track the finger motion, instead I am able to move the rectangle according to where a touch is registered. can someone please point me in the right direction? I know very little on the subject.

```
function handleMove(touchEvent) { var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); 
var root = document.documentElement; var touchX = touchEvent.clientX-rect.left 
- root.scrollLeft; var touchY = touchEvent.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop; 
return { x:touchX, y:touchY }; }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the issue you are describing.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what problem you got base on your code?

Comment: Instead of tracking touches and following the movement of a finger along a touch screen, the rectangle jumps to where a touch is on the touch screen instead. I would like a smooth movement, where the rectangle is following the touches instead of jumping to the touch.

Answer (score 0):

The [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) as mentioned in the link hold the current pointing position.
The moving is made by changing the position of your rectangle instance.
something like (pseudocode):

```
touchHandler(touchEvent){
     someScope.myRect.updatePosition(touchEvent.x, touchEvent.y)
}
```

Then, your application lifecycle/rendering cycle should make sure to correctly paint it, the cycle should be something like:

1. Read the current world attributes (objects in memory)
2. Paint the world accordingly
3. change the world attributes according to user requests
   and back to step 1....

Try reading some more on [Animations(with interactions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) and Double buffering,
You can learn about a possible implementation of the mentioned rendering cycle by looking at [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript).

Comment: function handleMove(touchEvent) {
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 var root = document.documentElement;
 var touchX = touchEvent.clientX-rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
 var touchY = touchEvent.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
 return {
  x:touchX,
  y:touchY
 };  
}

Comment: This is my argument, it's working except for the fact that the paddle jumps to where a touch is made instead of following the movement of my finger. I am not sure how to tweak the code, I am thinking I need to change the scroll property? I am not sure.

Comment: Can you add a link to some demo of your code? I'm not sure I quite understand, after it jumps to the touchevent position it stops moving? while you still drag your finger?

Comment: Or maybe, when the rectangle `pos=(0, y)` and you touch `pos=(1000,y) ` - you want the position to change gradually until reaches the final position? in that case you will need to implement an animation function - you can find example in the tutorial I sent

Comment: This part of the tutorial should help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations